# Is anyone in the Hulkbuster armor in the "Age of Ultron" trailer?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-age-of-ultron

In the trailer, it shows the Hulk battling what appear to be Iron Man in his Hulkbuster armor. Is he actually in the armor (his own armor inside of the Hulkbuster) or is Ultron controlling the armor to battle the Hulk?

Trailer is here:

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The 2015 Disney Shareholder meeting was recently held, and this scene was shown. The scene is [described as](https://www.cbr.com/new-avengers-age-of-ultron-clip-description-details-hulkbuster-brawl/):

> The scene opens with an armored police vehicle arriving on the scene. An incredibly angry and destructive Hulk is witnessed tearing up the streets, destroying cars and spreading all-out panic. Police, heavily armed with machine guns, openly fire on the Hulk to no avail. **In the distance comes Iron Man,** flying at super speed to the scene. "Hold your fire," he commands to the responding teams below. He is flanked by large metal objects that speed along through the air with him, keeping up every step of the way. We cut back to the menacing Hulk and all of a sudden, a large steel (?) surfboard-shaped object slams itself down in the pavement in front of him. Then another. And another. Before you know it, Hulk is trapped inside a giant, solid metallic "box." At least, that is, until Hulk smashes free and then continues his rampage. **And then, it assembles -- piece by piece -- the Hulkbuster, almost in Mark 42 fashion.** "The witch is messing with your brain," Stark tells Hulk. "You’re smarter than her, you’re Bruce Banner." This yields an even angrier response from Hulk and it’s on. Hulkbuster vs. Hulk. The Hulkbuster usually seems to have the upper-hand, as they drag each other through the streets, tearing up the pavement. At least until Hulk ends up on the Hulkbuster’s back, impaling the shoulder with a traffic light pole. **"Dick move, Banner" responds Stark as they continue to fight.**

<sup>(Read the rest of the description at the link at your own spoiler-peril)</sup>

Part of this scene, including verification of much of the description was confirmed with the release of [this 90 second clip](https://www.comingsoon.net/movies/trailers/429091-new-90-second-clip-from-marvels-avengers-age-of-ultron#/slide/1) which was shown during the 2015 MTV Movie Awards.

Answer (score 6):

When the Hulkbuster helmet comes down, it is over the regular Iron Man helmet. Presumably this is Tony Stark.

You can see this at 00:01:22.

[image: The Hulkbuster armour stands in the middle of the street with cars whizzing passed, the small Iron Man armour helmet can be seen sticking out of the top]

Comment: Oh that's true but it does not guarantee that the iron man armor contains Tony

Comment: That frame is literally all the information currently available about the Hulkbuster in the movie. As it stands currently, this question can not be answered any further.

Comment: @Huangism, nor that Tony himself is not controlled by another entity...

Comment: @Huangism If you're going to argue against the Iron Man armor containing Tony Stark then there probably won't be any satisfactory answer to your question until the movie comes out.

Comment: @Xantec I only asked because he is fighting the Hulk. I understand the Hulk sometimes loses control and goes crazy but the last film he only lost control due to Loki and the mind gem but I don't see how Ultron can make the Hulk lose control naturally I would assume Ultron has control of Iron man's tech

Comment: @Huangism If you don't mind speculative, potential spoilery review of the trailer this is a decent read: http://io9.com/shot-by-shot-breakdown-of-avengers-2-trailer-reveals-sp-1649782452

Comment: @Xantec thanks I will take a look, I did not read comics growing up and I want some background on the movie

Comment: @Huangism It is my understanding that the movies are meant to be completely separate from any past or present comic stories, so as long as you've seen all of the MCU then you should up to date. However, if you're interested the background of the characters extending to other media then you can probably find out more by asking about it in [chat].